# Decode encrypted password from tomcat server.xml using spring

Tags: java, spring

I have following configuration in my spring application

```
--main-context.xml
<bean class="com.crisil.ram.hdfc.util.SpringContextUtil" />   
<import resource="DataSource.xml"/>

--DataSource.xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>WEB-INF/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jdbc.jndiName}"/>
</bean>-->
```

instead of above bean definition I have used following definition

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="my.app.util.EncryptedDataSource">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jdbc.jndiName}"/>
</bean>

--database.properties

jdbc.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/MYAPPDB

--server.xml
<Context crossContext="true" debug="0" docBase="D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/MyApp" path="/MyApp" reloadable="true">
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" logAbandoned="true" maxActive="20" maxIdle="40" 
 maxWait="60000" name="jdbc/MYAPPDB" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYDESK:1521:u11g4777" username="user" password="cGFzc3dvcmQ="/><!--password-->
</Context>
```

Here is my EncryptedDataSource class for decrypting password which extends JndiObjectFactoryBean

```
package my.app.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.JNDIConfiguration;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class EncryptedDataSource extends JndiObjectFactoryBean{

    /*@Override
    public String getPassword() {
        String password = super.getPassword();
        password = decode(password);
        return password;
    }*/

    private String decode(String decode) {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        try {
            decode = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(decode));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decode;
    }

    private String encode(String encode) throws IOException {
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        encode = new String(encoder.encodeBuffer(encode.getBytes()));
        return encode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {

        EncryptedDataSource ed = new EncryptedDataSource();

        try {
            String password = ed.encode("password");
            System.out.println("password = "+password);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here I have used password which in encrypted format which I want to decrypt while connection pooling.
Please help.

Comment: (a) What is the problem? (b) Please note that base64 is not an encryption. It's merely an encoding (a different way to pass the same information, it requires no keys and can be decoded by anybody, including hackers).

Comment: If you have to encrypt your own source code/configuration files, you have a much bigger problem than you can ever solve with code. The usual way to solve this is by locking down the server physically: card access, log books, security guards, ...

Comment: Please be specific to question

Comment: Problem is, I have encrypted my database password and pasted in server.xml resource. Now while connecting to databse I want to decode it .I have configured like in spring config. Now I want to know how to get that password from server.xml in my java class  so that I can decode it and again set it to resource.

Comment: Please anybody can help me out